# UItableview section selected - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

''Hello World'' :)
 I have a UItableview with 4 different sections. I'm trying to  fill each sections with some rows depending on the section selected. I am **struggling** -__- to detect which section is selected in order to fill them accordingly. In my program I have  created 4 uibuttons (outside of the tableview and they represents each user; when a button is selected I use them to name the section header). Now I would like to link the button selected with the section.
 How one should proceed to know which section is selected. If button A is selected it would mean that  section 0 is selected then do operation x in section 0 (like inserting a new row for example);
 if button B is selected (i.e section 1 is selected) then Do operation y and so on...

Thanks in advance for helping a desperate soul

Answer (score 0):

Set tags for buttons.

```
button1.tag = 0
button2.tag = 1
button3.tag = 2
button4.tag = 3
```

then add targets

```
button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTouchButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTouchButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTouchButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
button4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTouchButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

then when button will select check sender tag and do operation on section

```
func didTouchButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let section = sender.tag

    //do operations in section
}
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) are examples of inserting and deleting rows in section based on section index. In Swift3 you should base on this methods:

```
func insertRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)
func deleteRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```